# Grav error when trying to install plugin - 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: grav

I am trying to install the grav code highlight plugin. When i run the following command in my terminal console from the project root:

```
bin/gpm install highlight
```

I get the following error:

> 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

How do i install the plugin using gpm and avoid this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php bin/gpm install highlight
```

should work (though it's not really a good solution, I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work without the 'php' added, and I've added php to  my PATH, and .php to PATHTEXT following https://markladoux.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/run-php-from-command-line-with-xampp-on-windows-7/ -- you could try that, but that is not a working solution for me, I still get this same error when trying to start a new grav project using composer ('bin/..) -> bin is not recognized as an internal or external command.)